# Get value from attribute with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, attributes

I have the following code:

```
echo "<div class='hp_container'><div id='hp' val=".$warrior_row[8]."></div></div>";
```

In this case, val has the value 8.

I want to access this value with JavaScript. I have tried the following method, but it keeps saying that txt is null.

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
   var txt = document.getElementById("hp");
   var f = txt.getAttribute('val');
   alert(f);
   </script>
```

How can I resolve this?

### Edit

I solved the problem by placing the code inside window.onload:

```
    window.onload = function() {
    var txt = document.getElementById("hp");
    var f = txt.getAttribute('val');
    alert(f);
};
```

Comment: There is no`val` attribute for the `div` element in HTML. If you want to use custom attributes then use `data-val`.

Comment: So long as your element is in your DOM before you run that JavaScript, that looks like it should work. So: have you tried putting your `<script>` before the closing `</body>` tag, rather than in the `<head>`? Further, as Quentin notes, custom attributes should be `data-` prefixed in order to validate.

Comment: I placed the code inside window.onload. That solved my problem.